# .htaccess works for virtualhost but not for public_html

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, debian, .htaccess

The problem is when I have a docroot pointing to some user's public_html/*. 
Say there is a virtualhost with Docroot /home/user/public_html/www - there .htaccess works. Yet when I go to example.com/~user/www the .htaccess does not work, Apache does not even read it ( I tested by creating garbled content in it).

My configuration for userdir is:

```
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    UserDir public_html
    UserDir disabled root

    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
            Options MultiViews -Indexes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch IncludesNoExec
            AllowOverride All
            <Limit GET POST OPTIONS>
                    Order allow,deny
                    Allow from all
            </Limit>
            <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS>
                    Order deny,allow
                    Deny from all
            </LimitExcept>
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

For vhosts:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName example.com
  DocumentRoot /home/user/public_html/www
</VirtualHost>
```

.htaccess in in /home/user/public_html/www

Answer (score 0):

When I had problems kinda like this, I used the Location directive bracket in addition to the Directory directive backet.